# Error while instantiating/upgrading the chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

After successfully installing the chaincode in dev-mode 
When I try to instantiate/upgrade my chaincode this error is shown-

> Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Failed to init chaincode(handler not found for chaincode mycc:1)

These are the commands I used-

Install command(no error in execution)-

```
peer chaincode install -p chaincodedev/chaincode/chaincode_example02 -n mycc -v 1
```

Instantiate command-

```
peer chaincode instantiate -n mycc -v 1 -c '{"Args":["init","a","100","b","200"]}' -C myc
```

Upgrade command-

```
peer chaincode upgrade -n mycc -v 2 -c '{"Args":["init","a","100","b","200"]}' -C myc
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check out:

1. Are you running your chaincode with following environment variables?

   CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGLEVEL=debug 
   CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1:7052 
   CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc:1
2. In your instantiate and upgrade command you are missing pointer to the ordering service e.g. you need to run it:

   peer chaincode upgrade -n mycc -v 2 -c '{"Args":["init","a","100","b","200"]}' -C myc -o orderingServiceIP:7051

Please also take a look into [tutorials](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/peer-chaincode-devmode.html).

Comment: - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
- CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer:7051

This is mentioned in docker-compose-simple.yaml

CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer:7051 CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc:0 ./chaincode_example02
this command is executed